# sendFrom with fee inclusive

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

> I am using Bitcoin JSON RPC 14 version so how can I use sendFrom
>   command in the case of fee inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendfrom` has these parameters:

```
sendfrom "fromaccount" "toaddress" amount , minconf, "comment" "comment_to"
```

As you can see there is no `subtractfeefromamount` boolean parameter.So you can't deduct fee from the amount itself.

You can use `sendmany` option with single destination address. `sendmany` has these parameter:

`sendmany "fromaccount" {"address":amount,...} ,minconf, "comment", subtractfeefrom`

Here `subtractfeefrom` in above parameter accept array of address from which fee will be deducted.

example:

```
bitcoin-cli sendmany "1521" "{\"n3jYBjCzgGNydQwf83Hz6GBzGBhMkKfgL1\":0.01}" 1 "" "[\"n3jYBjCzgGNydQwf83Hz6GBzGBhMkKfgL1\"]"
```

`n3jYBjCzgGNydQwf83Hz6GBzGBhMkKfgL1` will get 0.0098(approx) and not 0.01

Comment: question is about sendFrom command not about sendmany. :)

Comment: Yes you are right. But `sendfrom` has no `subtractfeefromamount` option but `sendmany` does. `sendmany` with single recipient address is equivalent to `sendfrom` . also `sendtoaddress` has no `fromaccount` option

Comment: Thanks Ajit sendmany has subtractfeefromamount option and sendfrom does not have and this helped me to fix my problem.